# Oracle hint on multiple indexes with multiple join statement

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a query as below :

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(A T1_IX01) INDEX(A T1_IX02) INDEX(B T2_IX01) INDEX(C T2_IX01)*/
       *
FROM   T1 A
JOIN   T2 B
ON     A.SOURCE = B.C1
JOIN   T2 C
ON     A.TARGET = C.C1;
```

and i need to use 2 indexes from T1 I created with SOURCE column and another with TARGET column which has mapped value with T2's C1 which is indexed as well.

With current state, it does only use one index from T1 which is stated as first hint but not the later one. **To summarize, I would like to use two different indexes created on same table for two separate joins.**

Why and how should i solve this issue to get faster result?

Comment: You can't. You could probably create a new index on multiple columns including a.source and a.target that would probably be used. However, if I were you, I'd avoid the hints and let Oracle sort it out for itself. Using indexes is not always a good thing, and full table scans are not always a bad thing.

Comment: I would leave it to oracle optimizer if the performance was acceptable. I used hints since Oracle optimizer does not always give best results as oppose to what you have said, since I'm joining two tables with hundreds of thousands of results together.

Comment: Are the statistics up-to-date?

Comment: What kind of statistics do you mean?

Comment: Optimizer statistics... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/stats.htm#PFGRF003

Comment: Is there a still need of updating optimizer statistics when the data I am joining are always new data?

Answer (score 1):

As @Boneist stated, let the optimizer do the work.

Also for any database it does not make sense (in most cases) to use 2 indexes for the same table. Once you traversed one index, you already have ROWID of the table block. From this block you can get values of *all* table's columns. So you not need to traverse any other index.

Rather than having two indexes, create one index with multiple columns.
As a rule of thumb order columns in the index by variance. Put most selective columns in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I have given hint to optimizer to use hash join instead of using indexes created, then the performance has gone up pretty high. Any other ideas would be appreciated.

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash */
       *
FROM   T1 A
JOIN   T2 B
ON     A.SOURCE = B.C1
JOIN   T2 C
ON     A.TARGET = C.C1;
```